# Pointing envvar to the top of an installation

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, nvidia-digits

I'm trying to install the text classification plugins for Nvidia Digits but am getting confused by the [installation instructions](https://github.com/NVIDIA/DIGITS/tree/master/examples/text-classification)

I installed Digits without a problem, but on looking for the Digits root am hitting a blank when trying add the plugins via Pip. I used 'whereis' to find Digits but on using that location Pip gives me an error, saying that it looks like a folder. What I should do to 'point to the  to the top of the Digits installation'?

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04.

From the instructions:

> install the top-level DIGITS package. Point the `$DIGITS_ROOT` envvar to the top of your DIGITS installation then do:
>
> $ pip install -e $DIGITS_ROOT
>
> Install the text classifications plug-ins:
>
> $ pip install $DIGITS_ROOT/plugins/data/textClassification
>
> $ pip install $DIGITS_ROOT/plugins/view/textClassification

Comment: Simple solution now I realise. I just downloaded the plugins directory from GitHub then in the pip install commands pointing to those directories (eg ~Downloads/Digits/plugins/data/textClassification)

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the plugins directory from GitHub then in the pip install commands pointing to those directories (eg ~Downloads/Digits/plugins/data/textClassification)